# Import datetime from .xlsx into .accdb

Tags: excel, vba, datetime, ms-access, import

I have been walking in circles about this for a while now, maybe you can help me out. I have an .xlsx export file, part of the table looks like this:

[image]

Two timestamps with a third column that measures the difference between the two. Next I want to import this file into my Access database like so:

[image]

I can assure you that these fields have been filled in without any spelling mistakes. However once I perform this step my data has been imported like this:

```
ALARM SOURCE TIMESTAMP  CLOSED TIMESTAMP    DURATION
30-12-1899 0:00:00  30-12-1899 0:00:00  30-12-1899 0:00:00
30-12-1899 0:00:00  30-12-1899 0:00:00  30-12-1899 0:00:00
30-12-1899 0:00:00  30-12-1899 0:00:00  30-12-1899 0:00:00
```

Is there a way to import this without losing all of my data? The .xlsx is a direct export and I don't really want to have to fiddle with an export everytime before using my .accdb. So the solution would have to be within Access.

Answer (score 0):

Try to *link* the Excel sheet and make sure to specify the timestamp fields as *DateTime*.

Then, run a query using the linked table as source and calculating the duration as:

```
CDate([Closed Timestamp]-[AlarmSourceTimestamp])
```

Use these data for your further processing.

To import/link from text, specify text as datatype and convert these:

```
CDate([Closed Timestamp])
CDate([AlarmSourceTimestamp])
CDate(CDate([Closed Timestamp])-CDate([AlarmSourceTimestamp]))
```

Comment: The linked sheet has the same issue as the directly imported one. All 3 columns including a datetime are saved as 30-12-2899 0:00:00, even if the columns are (automatically) defined as Date/Time columns in Access

Comment: Then they are neither numeric nor datetime. See edited answer, please.

Comment: If I understand you correctly I first need to do the linking process and afterwards do the query, right? If I do that it results in the columns being converted to "12:00:00 AM" as the data has already presumably gotten lost in the linking process.

Comment: Yes, but if you link as text, nothing gets lost as data are read "as is".

Comment: I don't get the option to read my columns a certain way while linking. I select which file I want to link, which sheet, if the first row contains headers, and that's it.

Comment: After that, click Next, and you can specify each column.

Comment: I don't reach that screen. Should I not use the "Linked Table Manager" under the External Data tab?

Comment: No, start from scratch: _External Data_ and then _New Data Source_, _From File_, _Excel_.